# Excel Data Forms

Tags: excel, vba, forms

I'm trying to create a skills matrix for work, but im not sure how to go about it, considering that Excel only allows you 32 columns in a data form.

My problem is that I need 57 columns, 1 Staff Name column and 56 jobs columns.

I was hoping to possibly have 1 normal text cell for the names, and check boxes for the other 56.

Any ideas on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you use a Table?

Comment: Wow! I never thought I would ever hear anyone mention a Data Form again!! These are relics of a bygone age, and while still usable, they lack any real configuration... As said, a Table might do, but otherwise it's a newer UserForm which you have to wire up in VBA. They have checkboxes etc

Comment: While i could use a table, i just want to make the data entry easier, considering i've got over 80 staff to enter data for

Comment: It's a little bit of a project if you're new, but a VBA Userform would be the way to go...

Answer (score 0):

Brian, you did throw Mac and I for a loop with your 'Data Form!' For your project - an easy way to several people to insert data into a spreadsheet - there's a million ways to do it. However, there are a few common guidelines:

1. No matter what holds the data, the user experience it what matters
2. Second, making dynamic code (especially with ranges), will do best
3. Using proper **error handling** will help keep you, the developer, in the know
4. You can use a simple UserForm, or an ActiveX sheet object to input data
5. Use smaller DataTypes & WorkSheet functions wherever possible; this will reduce system resources, and run faster

When you decide on a path, and want to learn specifics, please come back and post more at that time.

Danny,
[ExcelVBADude](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC5Z93LJulIuAICkZMSmcbGA?view_as=subscriber)

Comment: Thanks everyone, for your help. I've decided to look at using VBA UserForm.

Comment: @BrianDavies - let me kow fi you need any help. I have a YouTube channel and something like this would be fun! Also, let me know your feedback in a Live Stream via YouTube regarding an VBA Open House event! Best, Danny.